# Cache bust static url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, caching

We have website displaying images that are referenced using jquery and javascript.  The images are regularly updated in the Azure blob storage.  Can we add a date stamp or other variable to the end of url to prevent caching in the browser?

```
var baseURL = "https://someAzureblobContainer"
var token = "somereallylongToken"

$("#imageID").attr('src', baseURL + "someFilename" + token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You could do `$("#imageID").attr('src', baseURL + "file.jpg?token=" + token)` The web server will handle to the request like any other, yet as long as the URL path is different, the browser will not read from cache.

Comment: If the token is not changing, will this still work?  Because the URL path is now the same one from the last time you accessed.

Comment: @Jotter no the `token` must be unique each time. Otherwise the browser will cache and read from that on future requests.

Comment: The token variable is used for authentication so it must be included right after the filename.

Comment: @Jotter if that is the case, you can add another variable to the url. `$("#imageID").attr('src', baseURL + "file.jpg?token=" + token + "&r=" + randomHash);`